# PHP outputs NULL when encoding an array to JSON

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP array that I want to encode to JSON so I can later pass it in my JavaScript file.

When I tried that, the JavaScript outputted:

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token N"

I then tried to echo this JSON string in PHP and it outputted:

```
NULL
{
    "cg": "3",
    "cb": 0,
    "cc": "0%",
    "ci": "0",
    "wm": 0,
    "tl": "120"
}
```

Why is there a NULL?
Here's my code:

```
$table = array(
"cg" => $v1,
"cb" => $v2,
"cc" => $v3,
"ci" => $v4,
"wm" => $v5,
"tl" => $v6
);

echo json_encode($table);
```

**Edit to address the comments:**

In the database $v1 is varchar(255) and $v6 is int(11)

The value is retrieved like this:

```
function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue) {
    if($finder == "1") $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename");
    else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row[$rowname];
}
```

However this is not always the case, sometimes the value can be a simple string:
$v6 = "120";

Comment: What are the variable values, from `$v1` to `$v6`?

Comment: $v1 = fetchinfo("value","information","name","gID"); $num=  fetchinfo("number","g","id",$gID); $v6 = $num *13;

Comment: fetchinfo function gets information from MySQL database

Comment: And what exactly this `fetchinfo()` function returns, I mean does it return array, string, number? Please update your question with sufficient information.

Answer (score -1):

assuming the values of the variables are as shown in the above json data, I'm unable to reproduce the error - seems ok.

```
    $v1=3;
    $v2=0;
    $v3='%0';
    $v4=0;
    $v5=0;
    $v6=120;

    $table = array(
        "cg" => $v1,
        "cb" => $v2,
        "cc" => $v3,
        "ci" => $v4,
        "wm" => $v5,
        "tl" => $v6
    );

    echo json_encode( $table );
    /*
        {"cg":3,"cb":0,"cc":"%0","ci":0,"wm":0,"tl":120}
    */
```